# How to use edge insets in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How would I use edge insets to make an image fit inside a button? I'm not sure what values to use for the arguments in UIEdgeInsetsMake(). Could I somehow use the button's width and height to set them?

I want the button to just be an image when not selected. I understand how to do the "when not selected" part, but I have no idea how to use edge insets nor what the term exactly means.

I have this at the moment:

```
image = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(<#CGFloat top#>, <#CGFloat left#>, <#CGFloat bottom#>, <#CGFloat right#>)];

[button setImage:image forState:!UIControlStateSelected];
```

Also, how would I revert to using no image once the button becomes selected?

Comment: Could you provide some more details? What have you tried? Do you want the button to be just an image, an image with text on top, or what?

Comment: You will probably find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628004/how-does-uiedgeinsetsmake-works

Answer (score -2):

I think I am getting what you are saying.  Please let me know if I am misunderstanding your question.

Say you have `myImage.png`. Initialize it as the following:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Then, assuming you have connected an IBAction for the button in Interface Builder:

```
- (IBAction)myButtonWasPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [sender setImage:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how about using edge insets to shrink the picture and make it match the button's size?

Comment: Using `setBackgroundImage` instead of `setImage` should scale it appropriately.

Comment: If you are talking about setting the image to a size other than that of the entire button, that is when you would need to use edge insets.