# Understanding resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake?

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I dont get the `resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake`.
I have an icon that I want as a back button on the nav bar. 
It is 23x23 pixels (46x46 retina)..
But if i add 0,0,0,0 into the UIEdgeInsetsMake the icon looks very weird.
How am I suppose to do to make the icon look normal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7628068/1059705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your image, let's say you have 11pixels used as a border (left or top), a 1px central part and 11px used for the other border (right or bottom), you might wan't to use a 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0 UIEdgeInsets to preserve your borders from being distorted